# How do I build Python environment to deploy SSIS Package, or run SSIS locally?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I built an SSIS package with Execute Process Task commands to trigger Python scripts. Great! Now I need to deploy it. If I send it to a server, I will have to build a python environment on the server OS? Not an option, I don't have access.

Is there another way to set up the Python environment? Maybe call SSIS from the local command line with Windows Scheduler? Maybe deploy a local server to house my SSIS project? Is there a way to contact the DB, pull the contents of the SSIS job, and run it locally?

Comment: *"Not an option, I don't have access."* Then speak to someone that does. You can't run a Python File on a environment that does not have Python Installed.

Comment: *Maybe deploy a local server to house my SSIS project?"* Is your business happy to pay for more SQL Server licences for a second SQL Server instance on a different server you can manage? Considering you don't have access to manage the existing one, I doubt they would let you have your own one.

Comment: These are questions you probably should have asked at design time, not deployment time.

Comment: Help me understand what "set up the python environment" means, please. Do you need to install Python on the box? Install a package? Configure paths or dependencies? Something else?

Comment: I have a data science ETL pipeline. On my development machine I have multiple python environments. On the computer where SQL Server resides I do not have access to this environment. I cannot install python on this server.

Comment: What I am doing now is executing SSIS using DTexec from a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using calling dtexec on the ssis package from a batch file, and scheduling this batch file using Windows scheduler.